# setInterval() for an analogue clock

Tags: javascript, rotation, setinterval, clock

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I have trouble working with `etInterval()`.

I'm creating an analogue clock as an exercise. I have a function `setTime()` that gets and displays the time by rotating the arrows accordingly.

I want to execute this function again and again.

Here is my code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function setTime(){
            var d = new Date();
            var hour = d.getHours();
            var minute = d.getMinutes();
            var hourRotation = hour * 30 + (minute / 2);
            var minuteRotation = minute * 6;
            $("#small").css({
                "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + hourRotation + "deg)",
                "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + hourRotation + "deg)",
                "-o-transform": "rotate(" + hourRotation + "deg)"
            });
            $("#big").css({
                "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + minuteRotation + "deg)",
                "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + minuteRotation + "deg)",
                "-o-transform": "rotate(" + minuteRotation + "deg)"
            });
        };
        function clockStart(){
            setInterval(setTime(),1000);
            setTime();
        }
        clockStart();
    });
```

I'd like to understand this method and how to use it. The examples I could find looked so obvious, but still I can't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a function call in `setInterval()`.

What you want to do is :

```
setInterval(setTime,1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call you `setInterval` function, you don't pass the function reference as a parameter, but it's return value.
So you should use:

```
setInterval(setTime,1000);
```

or

```
setInterval(function(){setTime()},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `setTime()` in the line `setInterval(setTime(),1000);` is getting evaluated before the `setInterval()` function is called, and the results of the evaluation of `setTime()` are passed to the `setInterval()` function as an argument, rather than the function istelf being passed as an argument.

What you need to do is replace the function call ("`setTime()`") with this name of the function ("`setTime`") like this:
`setInterval(setTime, 1000);`